# Algorithm to implement a JOIN with some limitation

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Let me explain my matching problem with a real example (the problem is generic). Assume having **2 lists**: of **"selections"** loaded from different sources. **The list don't have duplicates.**

Let's say mkTPL.Selections and mkDB.Selections come from SQL Tables each with an unique index on the id and the selection's name. The problem is that sometimes IdSelectionType is null (in the selection from mkTPL.Selections)

```
foreach (var selTPL in mkTPL.Selections)
{   
    foreach (var selDB in mkDB.Selections)
    {
        if (selTPL.IsTheSame(selDB))
            selTPL.OddOrResultValue = selDB.OddOrResultValue;
    }
}

public bool IsStessaSelezione(SelectionPrints selDb)
{ 
    if (selDb.IdSelectionType == this.IdSelectionType)
        return true;
    else
    {
        bool isSameName = selDb.Name == this.Name;

        bool isSimilarName = false;
        if (!isSameName)
        {
            isSimilarName = RegexReplace(selDb.Name, @"\([\d.]+\)") == RegexReplace(this.Name, @"\([\d.]+\)");
        }

        return isSameName || isSimilarName;
    }
}
```

---

The match alghtoritm that I have implemented is not efficient. Once a selection is matched I shouldn't try to match it further with others (because of the unique index on the id and on the selection name).

Linq could provide me an easy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should `break` when you found a match:

```
foreach (var selTPL in mkTPL.Selections)
{   
    foreach (var selDB in mkDB.Selections)
    {
        if (selTPL.IsTheSame(selDB))
        {
            selTPL.OddOrResultValue = selDB.OddOrResultValue;

            break; // <--
        }
    }
}
```

Second, I would make a dictionary of `mkDB.Selections`, where you store the regexed value so you don't have to make that calculation over and over again, on every iteration.

Something like:

```
var mkDBDictionary = mkDB.Selections.ToDictionary(s => RegexReplace(s.Name, @"\([\d.]+\)"), s => s);

foreach (var selTPL in mkTPL.Selections)
{   
    string selTPLName = RegexReplace(selTPL.Name, @"\([\d.]+\)");

    if (mkDBDictionary.TryGetValue(selTPLName, out var selDB))
    {
        selTPL.OddOrResultValue = selDB.OddOrResultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a really nice idea.. there is just a small issue in my real problem. I've made the example simpler..

if I cannot find a match using the regexreplaced name I should use another criterium..

Let's say I have to try with the IdSelection if I have it, otherwise with the regex replace, otherwise with the position in the list of the element... is there a way to solve the my real complete problem?

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can make a fast lookup (like in my code) and for edge cases have a slow method which kicks in when the first match wasn't successful. You might be helped with a second dictionary too. It depends...